# LoDash: complete array with value until length

Tags: lodash

I am pretty sure the function exists in [LoDash](https://lodash.com), but I can't find it in the doc:

```
_.complete([el1, el2], 5, 0) // [el1, el2, 0, 0, 0]
```

A method that would complete an array until a certain `length`, with a certain `value`.

Does it?

Thanks

Comment: `_.mixin({"complete": function(arr, length, val) {
   l = length - arr.length
   return (l > 0) ? arr.concat(_.fill(new Array(l), val)) : arr
}});`

Comment: Perhaps you were thinking of `_.padEnd`? That's for strings though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is [`_.fill`](https://lodash.com/docs#fill), but it's not exactly what you want because it doesn't change the array length. You can, however, use it in combination with `_.assign`:

```
_.assign(_.fill(new Array(5), 0), ["a", "b"])
// returns ["a", "b", 0, 0, 0]
```

Note though that this returns a new array instead of mutating the existing one.

If you want to mutate the array, you can do this:

```
function complete(arr, val, length) {
    var oldLength = arr.length;
    arr.length = length;
    return _.fill(arr, 0, oldLength);
}
```

Comment: please note that doc says that fill mutates array